# json android: parsing json

Tags: android, json, parsing, listactivity

I have a json :

```
[ {user:"John",s:"Ldh",e:"usa"},{user:"Paul",s:"bukit panjang ",e:"FedExForum - Memphis"},{user:"ross",s:"bukit panjang ",e:"FedExForum - Memphis "}]
```

I am parsing this with the following code to retrieve all the values of "user" ..

```
public class ListViewAndroidActivity extends ListActivity {
private String newString, user;
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
TestServiceActivity test = new TestServiceActivity(); //This returns json from the server
   newString = test.readPooledFeed(); // returned json in string format

   JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(newString);
   int len = rootArray.length();
   for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
       JSONObject obj = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);

      user = obj.optString("user");
    results.add(user);
   }
}
```

This gives me no error.. but nothing is shown on the screen .. kindly help!

Comment: I don't see a field "u" in your json. Maybe you meant "user". Perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: check this: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

optString : Get an optional string associated with a key.

I don't see the key `u` in your JSON object, shouldn't it be `user = obj.optString("user");`

Comment: but still when i edit my json i don't get anything with the above code.. and i am using user instead of u! :|

Comment: Did you transform you json into a valid json object? If you do Arrays.deepToString(results) after the for loop, is it empty?

Comment: yup ... i did it .. let me see

Comment: Array.deepToString aint valid for arraylist type! Result is an arraylist!

Comment: Well, all I was trying to get at was whether results contained the content you where looking for in order to determine whether the fault was in this piece of code, the way you display it on the screen, or both.

Answer (score 0):

#### JSON formatting

Your JSON data is not valid, it's valid as javascript, but not as JSON.

All properties should be quoted in JSON:

```
[
 { "user": "John", "s": "Ldh", "e": "usa"},
 { "user":"Paul", "s":"bukit panjang ", "e": "FedExForum - Memphis" },
 { "user": "ross", "s":"bukit panjang ", "e":"FedExForum - Memphis "}
]
```

Indentation is not needed, I just did it to make it clearer.

#### Missing field

Your parser seems to ignore that your input data is invalid. Other problem could be as others mentioned you're requesting the `u` property at `user = obj.optString("u");` which does not exists.

Comment: @JoseVega because in JSON all properties should be quoted, as I mentioned. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: I realized what you where trying to say after I made my comment, I thought you had pasted his JSON object into your answer and when I validated that JSON is came back as valid, but didn't realize that his JSON didn't have quotes around the key.

Comment: @KARASZIIstván but still when i edit my json i don't get anything with the above code.. and i am using user instead of u! :|