# Android JSON, cant parse the below json

Tags: android, json

Android JSON, can't parse the below JSON

```
{
    "col": [
        "com",
        "Company"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            2068,
            "RAF"
        ]
    ]
}
```

JSON format

Comment: Cant parse means?? wt you are doing and wt you are getting...provide detailed info

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215193/json-android-parsing-json

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this JSON with this code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your jsonstring");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("your_json_array_name");
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
  String value = jsonArray.getString(i);
}
```

this will return the string value at "i"th index of JsonArray

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(" json string");
JSONArray jsonArrayColumns = jsonObject.getJSONArray("columns");
for(int i=0; i<jsonArrayColumns.length(); i++)
{
  String value = jsonArrayColumns.getString(i);
}


JSONArray jsonArrayRows = jsonObject.getJSONArray("columns");
for(int i=0; i<jsonArrayRows.length(); i++)
{
  String value = jsonArrayRows.getString(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse like this, But make your json bit standard-

```
try {
            parseJSON();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    private void parseJSON() throws JSONException {
        String json = "{\"columns\":[\"companyEventGroupIDUnique\",\"Company Event Group Description\"],\"rows\":[[206807106,\"RCB Home Games 2015\"]]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray columns = jsonObject.getJSONArray("columns");
        String column0 = columns.getString(0);
        String column1 = columns.getString(1);
        JSONArray rowsWrapper = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");
        JSONArray rows = rowsWrapper.getJSONArray(0);
        int row0 = rows.getInt(0);
        String row1 = rows.getString(1);

        Log.d("values-", "column0 " + column0 + " column1 " + column1 + " row0 " + row0 + " row1 " + row1);
    }
```

Comment: How am i supposed to print the data in text view??

Comment: You can do what you want to it. These are completely basic data types.
Simply you can set second argument of Log to your textview.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, `{}` represents an object and `[]` represents an array.

```
///so first get json object from response 

JSONObject jobj  =  response.getJSONobject();

////then after get array from jobj with array tag name

JSONArray ara1=jobj.getJSONArray("col");

////same as a second array


///////now get string value from array 

String name=ara1[0]...........
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"col": [
    "com",
    "Company"
],
"rows": [
    [
        2068,
        "RAF"
    ]
]
JSONObject json=new JSONObject("here goes the incoming string json");
JSONArray col,rows;
String com,company,number,raf;
```

here you split the JSONArray that way its easier to manage when they are larger ot at least its more readable

```
col=json.getJSONArray("col");
rows=json.getJSONArray("rows");
```

here you fetch the data from the separates arrays that are writen above

```
com=col.get(0).toString();
company=col.get(1).toString();

number=rows.get(0).toString();
raf=rows.get(1).toString();
```

this ways its better in case that you dont know the length of the arrays so you could iterate with a for and get an aray of Strings

```
ArrayList<String> colstring;
colstring = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<facilidades.length();i++)
{
  colstring.add(col.get(i).toString());
}
```